# SendGrid - Email with Dynamic Template and Multiple Recipients only showing dynamic data for one of the recipients?

Tags: python, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I'm trying to use SendGrid to send out emails to multiple recipients. I don't want the recipients to see each other's email, so I've tried two methods of accomplishing that:

- adding `is_multiple=True` to the `Email` constructor and setting `to_emails`
- adding personalizations with each name / email pair

In both cases, I'm using a dynamic template. I've tried setting the template data in two ways as well:

- `message.dynamic_template_data = {...python dict...}` (where `message` is the result from the `Email()` constructor)
- adding it to each personalization via `personalization.dynamic_template_data = {...python dict...}`

I'm testing this with two email addresses.

In all cases, one of the recipients gets the email formatted correctly. The other recipient receives an email with all of the dynamic data missing.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Correction:** I am getting it to work with the personalizations method - however, I'm sending the same data for each recipient... and I'd rather only send it once.

So the question is how to get this to work with a single copy of the `dynamic_template_data`?

Answer (score 2):

The helper libraries for SendGrid may simplify the [API structure of the Mail Send API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send), and as a result obfuscate it.

However, the `dynamic_template_data` is a property of the personalization object, so you have to provide it for each personalization, and to send emails to recipients without them seeing each other, you have to create a personalization per recipient. There's no way to use a single `dynamic_template_data` object, you have to provide one for each personalization.